# Summarize fail count and pivot type column at once in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this

```
ID <- c("ID001","ID001","ID003","ID003","ID003",
        "ID006","ID007","ID007","ID009","ID010")
Type <- c("Length","Breadth","Length","Breadth","Height",
          "Length","Length","Height","Breadth","Length")
FailCount <- c(3,7,2,3,9,7,3,2,3,9)

df <- data.frame(ID,Type,FailCount)
```

I am trying to subset this data frame by these conditions

1. Remove any ID with only 1 type
2. summarize the failcount
3. Pivot the Type column into 1 row separated with commas

My **desired output** is

```
     ID                    Type FailCount
  ID001         Length, Breadth   10
  ID003 Length, Breadth, Height   14
  ID007          Length, Height    5
```

I can remove the rows with only 1 type this way

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(n_distinct(Type) > 1)
```

How do I accomplish the other tasks? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `summarise` to get what you need:

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>%
    dplyr::filter(n_distinct(Type) > 1) %>%
    summarise(Type=toString(Type), FailCount = sum(FailCount))
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
library(dplyr)
        df <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(n_distinct(Type) > 1)%>%dplyr::summarise(Type=paste(Type,collapse=','),FailCount=sum(FailCount))

# A tibble: 3 × 3
      ID                  Type FailCount
  <fctr>                 <chr>     <dbl>
1  ID001        Length,Breadth        10
2  ID003 Length,Breadth,Height        14
3  ID007         Length,Height         5
```